# X-Mouse Button Control - Open folder in a new window

Tags: button, controls, mouse

I'd like to create a macro on my mouse middle button that will open a folder in a new window using the Ctrl+ENTER combination.

I've tryed the following: {LMB}{HOLD:1}{CTRL}{ENTER}
but it doesn't seem to work.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.